# Black background with image in center using GDI

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, gdi

Im displaying an image in the center of window. However I want all the other area of the window to be black. How do I achieve this?
Im using StretchBlt to center the image.Please advice

```
RECT clientRect,rect;
    HDC hDC = GetDC(hwnd);
    HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    ::SelectObject(hMemDC, bmp);
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &clientRect);
StretchBlt(hDC, clientRect.left, clientRect.top, newwidth, newheight, hMemDC, 0, 0,bmpdata.bmWidth, bmpdata.bmHeight,SRCCOPY);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ExcludeClipRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#) to clip out the area of the image, and then fill the background around it using [`FillRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162719%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#).